# Finding the inverse laplace transform of $\frac{3s+4}{s^2-16}$

Tags: laplace-transform

How would you find the inverse Laplace transformation of $\displaystyle \frac{3s+4}{s^2-16}$ when $s>4$? Thanks!!

I dont really understand what we need to do for this question. Please help

Comment: See here for [different techniques](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248330/inverse-laplace-transform-of-fraction-fs-large-frac2s1s29).

Comment: You really do not want to restrict $s$ to avoid the pole.

Comment: @MichaelRametta: if you have an issue with what you posted above and the DEQ, that sounds like a new question. You can post the ODE and your solution and we can figure out where it went wrong. Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Write the partial fraction fraction expansion as:

$$\displaystyle \tag 1 \frac{3s+4}{s^2-16} = \frac{1}{s+4} + \frac{2}{s-4}$$

Now, take the inverse Laplace of each of the terms on the right-hand-side (RHS) of $(1)$.

We have for $s \gt a$:

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{s-a}\right) = e^{at}$$

Clear?

Comment: +1. Have you seen this one? http://math.stackexchange.com/q/341507/8581

Comment: I hadn't, but now it has my curiosity up! Thanks for the reference!

Comment: so what would this answer be

Comment: $e^{-4t}$ for the positive term and $e^{4t}$ for the negative term.

Comment: Great i got i got the same answers thanks

Comment: so y(t)=e^(4t)?

Comment: I am not sure where $y(t)$ is coming from, but it would be $y(t) = e^{-4t} + e^{4t}$ (linear combination). If this is for an ODE you are solving, take this $y(t)$ and verify that it solves your equation. Clear?

Comment: im trying to find the inverse laplace transform i dont think that is correct for y(t)

Comment: has to be a simple mathematical error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8104/discussion-between-michael-rametta-and-amzoti)

Comment: + 1 Amzoti! ;-)