# Inverse Laplace Transform without tables

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

How can I show that the Inverse Laplace transform of $\dfrac{a}{s^2+a^2}=\sin at$ without the use of tables? Is there a formula or a direct way to do this?

Comment: You can use contour integration. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248330/inverse-laplace-transform-of-fraction-fs-large-frac2s1s29).

Comment: You are welcome.