# Find the inverse Laplace transform of $F(s)=\frac{5e^{−6s}}{s^2+4}$

Tags: laplace-transform

Find the inverse Laplace transform of
$F(s)=\dfrac{5e^{−6s}}{s^2+4}$

$f(t)=$ ***_*__*_*__*_*___**?

Here is my work:
$L{(5/2) \sin(2t)} = 5/(s^2 + 4)$, we have by the shifting theorem
$f(t) = (5/2) \sin(2(t - 6)) u(t - 6)$

Please help me with the correct solution. Thanks

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238).

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186943/calculate-inverse-laplace-transform). This problem is [more related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258380/finding-the-inverse-laplace-of-e-3s-frac1s-12).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already gotten the correct solution if by $u(x)$ you mean Heaviside unit step function $\theta(x)$. 
If you want to eliminate Heaviside function you could as well write
$$f(t)=\left\{\begin{matrix}0,&\ \text{if}~x<6\\ \frac{5}{2}\sin(2(t-6)),&\ \text{if}~x>6\end{matrix}\right.$$

Comment: what would the u equal in this case?

Comment: @Michael $u(x)=\theta(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}1: x>0\\ 0: x<0\end{matrix}\right.$

Comment: so how would i set up f(t) properlly

Comment: Almost the same as you've already written: $$f(t)=\frac{5}{2}sin(2(t-6))\theta(t-6)$$

Comment: In fact, your solution was already correct as I now see that $u(x)$ is also a common notation for Heaviside step function.

Comment: so there is no number that yo can substitue for theta?

Comment: No, theta is a function not a constant. You can instead write $f(t)$ as a piecewise function which in your case would be $0$ if $t<6$ and $\frac{5}{2}\sin(2(t-6))$ if $t>6$.